# Removing duplicates based on a partial match Python

Tags: python, duplicates

Say I have a list

```
var1 = ["VenueA/2003", "VenueA/2006", "VenueA/2009","VenueB/2009"]
```

What I want to do is remove all duplicate elements in the list based on the VenueX and keep the first occurrence
In the above example, there are three similar `VenueA` which are `VenueA/2003`, `VenueA/2006` and `VenueA/2009`. As `VenueA/2003` is the first occurrence, I want to keep that and remove the rest of VenueA

The result that I want is

```
var1 = ["VenueA/2003","VenueB/2009"]
```

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: loop over the list and build a new list.  as you loop you need to keep track of which prefixes have been seen, so you can decide whether to add the current item to the output list or not

Answer (score 0):

You can build a map keyed by the prefixes, and with as value, one of the strings that has this prefix. The `Map` constructor can be used for this.

As the Map constructor will retain the *last* occurrence of the string that has a given prefix, you should reverse the input and the output to get the *first* match instead:

```js
const arr = ["VenueA/2003", "VenueA/2006", "VenueA/2009","VenueB/2009"];

const map = new Map(arr.map(s => [s.split("/")[0], s]).reverse());
const result = [...map.values()].reverse();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
k=[]
for x in var1:
  if x.startswith('VenueA') and len(k)==0:
    k.append(x)
  if x.startswith('VenueB') and len(k)==1:
    k.append(x)

#output
['VenueA/2003', 'VenueB/2009']
```

Similarly, if you have more `Venues` you can increase the value of len and append them to `k`